# Laravel, cargar página mientras ejecuta Guzzle

Tags: laravel, blade, guzzle

Estoy trabajando con 2 vistas para leer un api con Guzzle.

En la primera se completa el formulario con los parametros para ejecutar el resultado específico del api.

y envia un post a la ruta donde esta el guzzle:

dominio.com/page1

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'gestor/results','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
        {{Form::token()}}
<input type="text" id="ejemplo1" name="parametro1" ></input>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

y tengo la ruta gestor/results con metodo POST al controlador GestorController@results

```
public function results()
{
$url = "dominioapi.com";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->get($url);
        $content = (string) $res->getBody();
    
        $results = json_decode($content, true);

        return view('results', ["results"=>$results]);
}
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, tarda como 4 segundos en cargar el guzzle... una vez que carga el guzzle, recién ahí muestra el resto de la web...

Hay posibilidad de cargar el resto de la página hasta que cargue los resultados?

En el mejor de los casos me tarda 4 segundos pero si la cantidad de resultados es mayor puede tardar hasta 10 segundos y es exageradamente mucho... ya que esos resultados se utilizan al final del siguiente formulario, y podrían ir completando el resto mientras carga.

Saludos!

Comment: No tengo mucha idea de Laravel y sus componentes; evalúa si es posible de manera asíncrona ejecutar el Guzzle, y mientras tanto mostrar la vista. Una vez esté el resultado de guzzle mediante websocket pudieras enviarle los datos al cliente.

Comment: Si no quieres que vaya hasta tu controlador y poder cargar toda la página, utiliza Ajax o algo desde el front o incluso podrías usar livewire.